# How can I calculate scroll percentage of a div instead of whole page with JS?

Tags: javascript

I found the following code used to track the scroll percentage as you scroll down the page.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){

var h = document.documentElement, 
    b = document.body,
    st = 'scrollTop',
    sh = 'scrollHeight';

var percent = (h[st]||b[st]) / ((h[sh]||b[sh]) - h.clientHeight) * 100;

document.getElementById('scroll').textContent = 'scrolled: ' + percent + '%';

});
```

That shows the percentage of the whole page. If I only want the scroll percentage of a specific div like this example https://www.thefarmersdog.com/ how the dog bowl scrolls over when you move down the page.

Answer (score 1):

Divide number of pixels that an element's content has been scrolled vertically by the height of an element's content minus an element's offset height and multiply by 100 to get percentage value from 0 to 100. Optionally, round it to get an integer value.

**scrollPercent** = [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) / ([scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) - [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight))

```
const scrollLabelElement = document.getElementById('scroll');

element.addEventListener('scroll', (_event) =>
    const percentScrolled = Math.round(element.scrollTop / (element.scrollHeight - element.offsetHeight));
    scrollLabelElement.textContent = `Scrolled: ${percentScrolled}%`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getBoundingClientRect()`

```
const coordinates = document.getElementById('your-id').getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(coordinates.top); // This is the distance to the top of the screen
```

Here is a [detailed article](http://javascript.info/coordinates) that you can read if you need more info.